# How do I make CSS tab ui into a nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the following tabs into bootstrap nav fixed at bottom. However, it stays on top and how do I create the navigation bar with what I have. Thank you. [Here](http://www.z1labs.com/tabsnavigation.html) is the incorrect page. Tab "One" has its own ul but does not show. Tab One should show "page 1" and "page 2".

html body:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#content").find("[id^='tab']").hide(); // Hide all content
  $("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current"); // Activate the first tab
  $("#content #tab1").fadeIn(); // Show first tab's content

  $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
       return;       
      }
      else{             
        $("#content").find("[id^='tab']").hide(); // Hide all content
        $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
        $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
        $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for the current tab
      }
  });
});
```

```css
#tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#tabs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 0;
}

#tabs a {
  position: relative;
  background: #ddd;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #ddd);  
  padding: .7em 3.5em;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.8);
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

#tabs a:hover,
#tabs a:hover::after,
#tabs a:focus,
#tabs a:focus::after {
  background: #fff;
}

#tabs a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

#tabs a::after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: -.5em;  
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1em;
  background: #ddd;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff, #ddd);  
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  transform: skew(10deg);
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;  
}

#tabs #current a,
#tabs #current a::after {
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 3;
}

#content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 2em;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2; 
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse fixed-bottom">

<nav>
  <div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" name="tab1">One</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">page 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" name="tab2">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="tab3">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="tab4">Four</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `.navbar` css to `display:fixed`, `bottom:0` and remove margin: bottom

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to follow using the code above but you can try `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;`

Example:

```
#tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

or change the position of the navbar itself:

```
.navbar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```